# how can i get specified columns after merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_connection_str='mysql+pymysql://developer:password@192.132.1.11:3308/pos'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
df=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='tbl_store_inventory',con=db_connection)
df1=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='tbl_batch_detail',con=db_connection)
df2=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='tbl_product', con=db_connection)
df3=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='tbl_store', con=db_connection)

one=pd.DataFrame(df)
two=pd.DataFrame(df1)
three=pd.DataFrame(df2)
four=pd.DataFrame(df3)
result=pd.merge(one, two, how='inner', on='BatchID')
result1=pd.merge(result, three, how='inner', on='ProductID')
result1
```

I am getting all the columns after merging two dataframes, how can I get  columns of my choice?

Here i am getting 77 columns after executing this code. Let say I want to get only 10 columns: 5 from `df1` and 5 from `df2`, how can I get this?

Comment: result1[['col1','col2',...]] like this provide list of columns you want.

Comment: Hi, I ajusted the formatting of your question, so that it is easier to read by the many that will find your subject interesting. Take care to this: you write once, when lots will read! :)

Comment: ok @Joël Thanks, from next time i'll do this carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the column list in the Dataframes as in the snippet below

```
result = pd.merge(df1[['col1', 'col2']],
                 df2[['col1', 'col3']],
                 on='col1')
```

Comment: Hi @anuragpandey, If the solution helped you please tick the solution and add an upvote. It would help me and other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the column names as the parameters in pd.dataframe(df, columns)
df is the data frame name
Parameter-
columns: Index or array-like
Column labels to use for resulting frame. Will default to RangeIndex (0, 1, 2, …, n) if no column labels are provided